# "Must be of an array type but is resolved to string"....Why and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm supposed to create a code that will basically act as a calculator for the operators +,-,*,/, and %. I've posted the code below.

import java.util.Scanner; 
public class TestCode {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter an operation: "); 

        String userOperation = input.nextLine(); 

        if (userOperation.length() != 3) {
          System.out.println(
            "Usage: java Calculator \"operand1 operator operand2\"");
          System.exit(0);
        }

        // The result of the operation
        int result = 0;

        // Split items from a string 
        String[] tokens = userOperation[0].split(""); <===== Error line 

        // Determine the operator
        switch (tokens[1].charAt(0)) {
          case '+': result = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) +
                             Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    break;
          case '-': result = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) -
                             Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    break;
          case '*': result = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) *
                             Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    break;
          case '/': result = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) /
                             Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        }

        // Display result
        System.out.println(tokens[0] + ' ' + tokens[1] + ' ' 
          + tokens[2] + " = " + result);
      }

}
```

I've tried pretty much everything that I can think of. What do I need to do to change it, and why is it currently not working? Thank you!!!

Comment: You are getting an error because you didn't give it anything to split by. See Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

`userOperation`  is a String:

```
String userOperation = input.nextLine();
```

You later treat it as an array:

```
userOperation[0]
```

You can't do that.  If you want to grab a specific character from a String in Java, then do the following:

```
char c = userOperation.charAt(0);
```

**SIDENOTE**:  I'm not sure what you're ***exactly*** doing with this `.split("");`, but I think you should probably split your String into tokens more carefully (probably via Regex).

Comment: Also, in case you ever need to split a String in their chars use `char[] array = myString.toCharArray();`

Comment: @DWilches Good to note that too.  It really depends on what OP wants, but I can imagine he needs that too

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
userOperation.split("")
```

`userOperation` is a simple String, not an array so you cannot access it with `[]`.